# Cleaner way to convert an array of compact float values into an array of floats

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, types, casting

Before the actual question, small prelude. I don't care about security, I do care about performance. I KNOW this is not proper and I know it's very hacky, however this is quite fast.

`vector<float> result = move(*((vector<float>*)&vertices));`

That code is abusing C style casts and pointers to force the compiler to interpret the left hand side array `vertices` which is a vector of a compact type where all the fields are float as an array of floats.

i.e

```
struct vertex {
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
}
vector<vertex> vertices;
```

This works and does what it needs to, however it's somewhat hard to read. I want to know if there is another way of achieving the same outcome in a more readable way.

Comment: I would say a `vector::resize` plus a `std::memcpy` should do the trick without all the casting

Comment: That actually copies the data however, to my udnerstanding what I posted above does not do any copyng, it reinterprets a pointer.

I.e the snippet should be constant as far as I know

Comment: Your code won't work if the vector stores its size instead of an end pointer. However, if your code happens to work, it will probably have better performance than a well defined solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you should care more about is that the behaviour of your code is *undefined* since the cast is a violation of the *strict aliasing* rule. Note that `vector<vertex>` is a *completely different* type to a `vector<float>`.

In particular you are assuming the data in the `struct` are contiguous and there is no padding in the `struct`, even at the end.

Why not use a `vector<float>` from the get-go, with a note to self that the 4th element starts the next triangle, and so on?

Comment: Because this code is trying to handle generic data, so the only imposition is that the struct definition is contiguous and without padding.

Any arbitrary structure that obeys this should be valid input for the method I am building

Comment: Even so you're still in undefined behaviour land. I wonder what gcc does with optimisation cranked up to the max, for example.

Comment: If that breaks this then you can use compiler directives to disable optimizations for that snippet.

As long as this UB works in the 4 systems it needs to work in, I am ok even with it breaking in the future

Comment: Seems like you're wanting to have a good old punch up with the C++ standard. I wouldn't do that if I were you!

Comment: @Makogan How do you know exactly what "disable optimizations" does under the hood, either with the current compiler you're using, or a future version?

Comment: The other thing is, if compactly defined structures are no longer compact and without padding, I have bigger issues, because all Graphics APIS rely on those features to communicate between teh GPU and the CPU

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't so the only thing I can do is test this code to hell and try to catch it as soon as it stops working, but right now, speed > everything else. Fast UB is better than slow DB for now