# Constant time construction / reinterpretation of vectors of compatible data?

Tags: c++, vector, types, type-conversion, undefined-behavior

A common issue I find when coding is, I have multiple container types that all represent the same thing in memory, but appear under different types.

For example in graphics you could have an std vector of floats and an std vector of glm vec3s.

Both of those are essentially a contiguous array of floats where the data is interpreted like:
`{{x,y,z}, {x,y,z} ...}`

Converting from one into the other can be done in many ways, some more efficient than others. One of the simplest ones is to just grab the pointers and work at the pointer level directly. i.e

```
vector<vec3> v1;
float* ptr = (float*) v1.data;
```

The above will allow you treat that pointer as a pointer to a float array (assuming you use the correct indexing). And it can be done as constant operation.

However this doesn't transfer ownership of the data, and can lead to dangling pointers, for example if you did:

```
float* GetPtr()
{
    vector<vec3> v1;
    return (float*) v1.data;
}
```

The above is clearly going to cause issues.

In order to get constant time conversion of types, I use a method that abuses undefined behavior to get things working:

```
vector<float> GetVerts()
{
    vector<vec3> vertices;
    /* Call some function that returns the data as vec3's */
    vector<float> result = move(*((vector<float>*)&vertices));
    return result;
}
```

This is a massive hack that abuses the fact that SOME but NOT ALL implementations of stl vectors use pointer based representations to index their data. Under those implementations, the above code works, because all the pointer based arithmetic depends exclusively on the type and the distance between pointers, so the conversion doesn't break anything.

This has the advantage that if you have 2 libraries that have different structures representing the same data. You don't waste cpu cycles converting data that doesn't need to be converted.

That hack has been useful when doing quick hacky prototypes in which all I care is speed and not properness.

I am looking however for a proper way to achieve something like this without relying on a specific implementation of the STL.

The primary purpose of this is, there's a plethora of libraries out there that deal with geometric data, and wasting CPU cycles just to bypass type checks is problematic for performance. Having 2 different libraries both have their own type of a 3D vector is irrelevant when at the end of the day, any such array is just a continous array of floats where every 3 floats represents a vertex position.

Is it possible to do constant time construction / reinterpretation of one vector of one type to another without relying on UB?

PS: I tried asking this before: [Cleaner way to convert an array of compact float values into an array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61374833/cleaner-way-to-convert-an-array-of-compact-float-values-into-an-array-of-floats/61374924?noredirect=1#comment108574882_61374924)

But I think the lack of context is making people focus on "this is not a good idea" instead of the more relevant issue of "this works and is necessary for my use case, how can I make it better?". Which is why I am trying to make a better question with more context and pertinent examples.

Comment: If you want portable code, the answer is no. C++20 though introduces some new lifetime rules and features to help enable stuff like this, I just don't know if it does everything you want as it's too new to me.  Hopefully someone else can tell you more.

Comment: `float* ptr = (float*) v1.data();` accessing ptr is UB due to strict aliasing rules.

Comment: In general yes, for the example I provided no. Because the types are compatible, if they weren't it would be impossible to send that data to the GPU and expect valid behaviour.